# could not bind value to parameter

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hql

I'm running a query in Java using HQL and creating a parameter that looks like this:
`query.setParameter("month", month);`

The month variable is a BigDecimal that is between 1 and 12. However, the month variable was passed to the function running this query as an Object. So when it is being set as a parameter it is seen as an Object.

When I run the query I get this error:

```
15:46:48,878 INFO  [IntegerType] could not bind value '4' to parameter: 1; java.math.BigDecimal
15:46:48,878 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal
15:46:48,878 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.set(IntegerType.java:41)
15:46:48,878 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:136)
15:46:48,879 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:116)
15:46:48,879 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:38)
```

The '4' is the value stored in my month variable. So it's obviously something wrong with that parameter. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Are you using HQL, or [JPQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API#The_Java_Persistence_Query_Language) (e.g. Hibernate, or JPA)?

Comment: The query is completely written in HQL.

Comment: And why are you using a `BigDecimal` to store values between 1 and 12?

Comment: Because the functions that get the month and year to pass as parameters return BigDecimals. All the other queries I've made do the exact same thing. But for some reason this one just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It was just a problem trying to add a BigDecimal to a constant number within the query.